# Difference between an eigenvalue and a spectral value

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

What is the difference in the definition of a spectral value and an eigenvalue. My notes from functional analysis says

> $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an operator $A$ if $\,\exists \, x \in \mathbb{C^n}$ such that $$Ax = \lambda x$$ This implies $(A - \lambda I)x = 0  \Rightarrow \ker(A - \lambda I) \neq {0}$. This is equivalent
>   of saying that $A$ is not injective.

On the other hand, the definition of a spectral value is

> $\lambda$ is called a spectral value of $A$ if $A - \lambda I$ is not
>   invertible.

What is the difference here? How is it that some operators can have spectral values and not eigenvalues (eigenvalues $\subset$ spectrum(A)) and lastly, how do they conincide when the space is finite dimensional ?

Comment: it only makes difference if the space is not of finite dimension.

Comment: @abel:How $\ker(A - \lambda I) \neq {0}$ is equivalent
of saying that $A$ is not injective?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the unilateral shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, i.e.
$$
S(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(0,a_1,a_2,\ldots).
$$
It is easy to verify that $S$ is injective, so $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $S$. But $S$ is not invertible (because it is not surjective). So we have $0$ as an element of the spectrum of $S$, but not an eigenvalue.

In finite dimension, two things happen: since the domain and codomain are of equal finite-dimension, an operator is injective if and only if it is surjective. And all linear operators are continuous. So if $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible, this means that it is not bijective; then it is not injective, so it has a nonzero kernel, i.e. there exists nonzero $x$ with $Tx=\lambda x$. Thus, in finite dimension the spectrum consists only of eigenvalues.

Comment: So if I have this correctly, $S$ is injective so $\ker(S - \lambda I) = {0}$ and thus $0$ is not an eigenvalue. 

But  since $S$ is not surjective, $\ker(S - \lambda I) \neq {0}$. How can this be? How can the kernel be both empty and non empty

Comment: Actually, my bad. We are talking about a specific $\lambda = 0$. $A$ could potentially have other eigenvalues. But $0$ is not one of them and this implies $\ker(A) = {0}$ NOT $\ker(A-\lambda I)$. Infact because $\ker(A - \lambda I) \neq {0}$ it follows there are spectral values. Now I am trying to think why 0 is a spectral value.

Comment: Ignore comments, the first paragraph on wiki link cleared up the confusion for me. But my question is that when an operator $A$ has eigenvalues, is it true that $\ker(A- \lambda I) \neq {0}$ or $\ker(A) \neq {0}$

Comment: Having an eigenvalue $\lambda $ **means** that $\ker (A-\lambda  I)\ne\{0\} $. The $S $ in my answer has no eigenvalues  (easy exercise).

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:which element of "S" does not have the preimage?

Comment: @P.Styles: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean. $S$ is an operator.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:My bad, Since $S$ is not invertible,but injective it means $S$ is not surjective ...I want to know which element of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ does not have have pre-image?

Comment: $(1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 3):

As you acquire examples, please be sure to include this multiplication operator:
$$
                           X = L^{2}_{\mu}(-1,1),\\
                            (Af)(x) = xf(x).
$$
Here, $\mu$ is a finite Borel or Lesbesgue measure on $[-1,1]$. The reason to include this one in your collection of examples is that bounded selfadjoint operators with $\sigma(A) \subseteq [-1,1]$ can be essentially viewed as copies of this operator. If $\mu$ has an atom at $\lambda \in [-1,1]$ (i.e., $\mu\{\lambda\} \ne 0$,) then $\chi_{\{\lambda\}}$ is an eigenfunction of $A$ with
$$
           A\chi_{\{\lambda\}}=\lambda \chi_{\{\lambda\}}
$$
If $\lambda$ is not an atom of $\mu$, but $\lambda$ is in the support of $\mu$, then
$$
\begin{align}
               \|(A-\lambda I)\chi_{[\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon]}\|^{2} & = \int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}|\lambda-x|^{2}\,d\mu(x) \\
   & \le \epsilon^{2}\|\chi_{[\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon]}\|^{2}
\end{align}
$$
In other words,
$$
       u_{\epsilon}= \frac{1}{\|\chi_{[\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon]}\|}\chi_{[\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon]}
$$
is a unit vector for which $\|(A-\lambda I)u_{\epsilon}\| \le \epsilon$. So $u_{\epsilon}$ is an approximate eigenvector. Even though there is no eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, there is a unit vector which is nearly an eigenvector, to any desired degree of approximation. In this case $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$; the inverse of $A-\lambda I$ is unbounded and only densely-defined.

Comment: Ah, i see. I'll have to go through this again as its a bit difficult for me (and I have very little experience with measure theory - but I don't think that's entirely relevant here)